# Select a default value of a Combo box in Centura/Gupta (Team Developert)

Tags: opentext, guptateamdeveloper, centura

I am trying to configure a combo box so that it shows a default value and does not show empty.

The structure is as follows:

```
`ccmbDynamic: cmbcombo
-List Initialization
*Message Action
 *On PAM_Create
 -Set nMyObjectID = 1
 -Call clsDynamicListPopulateFull('Table_name', 'code_id', 'Description', 'Condition Where', 
                                  'code_id', 1, CMD_Description, DT_Number, CMD_ForceFetch)
 -Call SalsendMsg(cmbcombo, SAM_Click, 0, 0)

 *On PAM_SAM_Click
 -Call IntSqlInmediately ('SELECT code_id FROM Table_name WHERE Condition')`
```

Does anyone know what process I am doing incorrectly? The queries return the correct information, but the selection is not reflected in the combo (The selected default), only when I click is that the information is seen, I need it to be seen before the click, some help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what is happening at class level ( ccmbDynamic ) as you don't show it.

In fact it's not clear what any of this code is doing.

But a much easier way to Populate a combo is to use **SalListPopulate ( hWndCombo, hSql, 'Your select Statement' )**, and this will fetch from the dB and fill the combo at the same time.  If you then want to select a specific entry in the combo, call **SalListSetSelect ( hWndCombo, nIndexToSelect )** e.g. **SalListSetSelect ( hWndCombo, 0 )** to select the first entry.  e.g.

```
On SAM_Create
  If SalListPopulate( hWndCombo, hSql, 'SELECT code_id FROM Table WHERE 
                                       Condition' )
     ! Set list box selection to the first item.
     ! If you specify -1, SQLWindows deselects the selected entry
     Call SalListSetSelect( hWndCombo, 0 )
```

p.s. Unrelated to the question, but worth mentioning.... I do hope your user function **IntSqlInmediately** does not actually call the builtin function **SqlImmediate**() ( you'd best check this out ) - as this was depricated many years ago by Gupta in favour of **SqlPrepareAndExecute**(hSql, 'Your select Statement') followed by **SqlFetchNext**(hSql, nFetched).  The reason SqlImmediate() was depricated, was that programmers were too lazy to release the internal handle connected by the function, by then calling **SqlClearImmediate ()**.  So if you insist on using SqlImmediate() - remember to follow with SqlClearImmediate() . Otherwise those internal handles will buildup ad-infinitum until you get a GPF.

Comment: I can confirm that
Call SalListSetSelect( hWndCombo, 0 )
is the way to show the first entry in the list.

Comment: Steve, I don't get a GPF when using SqlImmediate(...) e.g. 10.000 times in a row. Internally TD connects ONE cursor for SqlImmediate(..) and keeps it connected until you issue SqlClearImmediate(..) or until the end of the programm. So there is not a real resource problem here. I don't understand why Gupta says the function is deprecated. But you really should know how to use it because of performance issues. You should not use it just for lazyness.

Comment: Hello Thomas  Thanks for the insight - and I agree with the one internal handle, but the GPF point is mute, as it completely depends on the communication protocol being used. Try using SqlImmediate ( or SqlExists )  with OLEdB - you will get a GPF regardless ( or 'invalid cursor' at least ) . Also I was trying to point out that using SqlImmediate is bad style  - not to be encouraged, as the Sql will be re-PreparedAndExecuted every time it is called - even if already Prepared. And in reality, a Handle pool with pre-Connected handles should be being used I believe.